# SQL Server Database protection

Tags: vb.net

I want to secure my SQL Server Database so that no one could open it or access programatically without a password.
How can I do it?
I tried the security section of SQL Server Management Express but it is too complicated for me.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: It may be complicated, but that's the right way to do this. Learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx) about SQL Server login creation.